# Can a neutron decay into a proton + muon (+ muon-neutrino)

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, radiation, neutrons, leptons

Can a neutron, if it has enough kinetic energy, decay like:

$ \hspace{0.3cm} n \rightarrow p + \mu^- + \bar{\nu}_\mu $

I assume it's not allowed since it's not on the possible decay modes on the Particle Data Group (http://pdg.lbl.gov/), but I don't know if they only account decays allowed from rest masses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinetic energy does not matter. In its own frame, the neutron does not have enough mass/energy to decay in a proton and a muon.